# how to use promise for show data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to get all data from mongoose , but that not working and tell me this error message:

ReferenceError: docs is not defined

i use Handlebars for showing, because of this defined list

by the way i want to use promise , how can i fix this error:

```
exports.showListEmployee = (req,res) => {
Employee.find()
.then(res.render('employee/list') , {
    viewTitle: 'List Employee!!',
    list:docs
}
)
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error Show List' + err)
})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `docs` supposed to be a result of `Employee.find()` then you didn't indicated it as a parameter for an arrow function passed to `then`. Another issue is ')' in wrong place.

```
Employee.find()
.then(docs => res.render('employee/list' , {
    viewTitle: 'List Employee!!',
    list:docs
})
)
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error Show List' + err)
})
```

Comment: why i can't define docts inside find?

like this = employee.find(docts)

Comment: because `find` awaits a function and it passes results to it

Comment: it's common approach instead of mutating an array passed as an argument